# Gridlayout spacing changes in every key stroke

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a small issue. I have a search bar on my android app, and when I type something to search bar, the spacing of the grid layout is changing.

[image: Grid layout initial state]

[image: Grid layout after search result]

My adapter:

```
class MostSearchedAdapter(
    private val list: List<MostSearched>,
    private val click: OnClickListener
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MostSearchedAdapter.MostSearchedViewHolder>() {
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MostSearchedViewHolder {
        val binding = ItemSearchbarNoResultImageBinding.inflate(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
            parent,
            false
        )
        return MostSearchedViewHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = list.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MostSearchedViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(list[position])
    }

    inner class MostSearchedViewHolder(val binding: ItemSearchbarNoResultImageBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        fun bind(item: MostSearched) {
            binding?.image.setImageResource(item.searchedImage)
        }
    }

    interface OnClickListener {
        fun onItemClick(item: MostSearched)
    }
}
```

Initialize the adapter on my fragment

```
private fun setMostSearchAdaptor(data: List<MostSearched>) {
    binding?.rvMostSearchedItems?.apply {
        val mAdapter = data?.let {
            MostSearchedAdapter(it, object: MostSearchedAdapter.OnClickListener {
                override fun onItemClick(item: MostSearched) {
                }
            })
        }
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        adapter = mAdapter
        adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()

        val gridLayoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this@SearchbarListFragment.context, SPAN_COUNT)
        layoutManager = gridLayoutManager
        addItemDecoration(
            GridDividerItemDecoration(
                resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.margin_image_view_1),
                SPAN_COUNT,
                resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.margin_image_view_10)
            )

        )
    }
}
```

I call `setMostSearchAdaptor` from fragments' `onViewCreated` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the problem is that on every search result you add on more item decorator:

```
    addItemDecoration(
        GridDividerItemDecoration(
            resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.margin_image_view_1),
            SPAN_COUNT,
            resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.margin_image_view_10)
        )
    )
```

**Extract the aforementioned part from `setMostSearchAdaptor`**.

You must add decorator only once to avoid your issue. Add item decorator from `onViewCreated` explicitly. If you are holding a reference to your root view then make sure you add item decorator only once. In this case, you can do it from `onCreateView`.

```
class YourFragment extends Fragment {
    private View rootView;

    @Override 
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
            @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (rootView == null) {
            // inflate rootView
            // add item decorator to grid layout
        }
        return rootView;
    }
}
```